# Need to take Heap Dump after JVM EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: java, memory, heap-dump, oql

I found out heap dumps can be taken using java command parameters: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError writes heap dump on OutOfMemoryError and -XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak writes heap dump together with thread dump on CTRL+BREAK.

Now I need heap dumps when I am getting the following error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x5fb62488, pid=6332, tid=6336
```

I am getting the hs_err_pid6332.log, but I need heap dump in the HPROF format so that I can run OQL on the content.

Can you guide me here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you want a heap dump after a JNI module just dereferenced a bad pointer?

Comment: I have actually injected this bad code inside my program. After it crashes I want to analyze what values the program variables hold. I need this for a particular reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract an HPROF heapdump from the core file that is produced from the crash:

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof ${path_to_java_exe} ${path_to_core}
```